# googleapi: Error 403: credential does not have storage.buckets.create access. Permission 'storage.buckets.create' denied on resource, forbidden

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-template-file, google-cloud-storage

I am learning Terraform with GCP and trying to authenticate using service account (keys.json) and create a gcs bucket using terraform.

```
provider "google" {
    project = "terraform-gcp-401813"
    region = "asia-south1"
    zone = "asia-south1-a"
    credentials = "keys.json"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "GCS1" {
    location = "asia-south1"
    name     = "bucket-using-tf"
}
```

I am getting below error while `terraform apply`

```
google_storage_bucket.GCS1: Creating...
╷
│ Error: googleapi: Error 403: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.create access to the Google Cloud project. Permission 'storage.buckets.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist)., forbidden
│ 
│   with google_storage_bucket.GCS1,
│   on main.tf line 8, in resource "google_storage_bucket" "GCS1":
│    8: resource "google_storage_bucket" "GCS1" {
```

As error suggest I given Storage Admin permission direclty to client_email in `key.json` file using IAM Admin Panel but still its keeps on giving same error. Am I missing any steps? Thanks in adavace!

Answer (score 1):

My Bad! I had given storage admin permission in default GCP project. I had to select the correct project from dropdown menu and then give the role to credential email.